# Is there a working TYPO3 V8 Captcha?

Tags: forms, content-management-system, typo3, captcha

is there a working TYPO3 V8 Captcha which i simply can add into my form?

I searched but there wasn't any working on our Page.

If you know one, could you explain how to use or install it?

Kind regards,
Alex

Comment: [pxa_form_enhancement](https://github.com/pixelant/pxa_form_enhancement) is working here with Typo3 8.7.9

Answer (score 4):

"Official" answer from the form dev team :) There is a built in spam protection. In version 8, we have included a honeypot field. This honeypot field is changing its name, position and order within the form by each page refresh. At the moment, we are planning the features for version 9 and think about integration even more spam prevention checks.

I think Sebastian Fischer is working on a recaptcha extension for version 8, see https://github.com/evoWeb/recaptcha.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Is there a documentation about that? So users of TYPO3 like me, don't have to search hours in the Internet :/

Comment: We have a code sprint in September. I will take care of the documentation and add those information.

Comment: Nice! Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

There is now a release of EXT:recaptcha in TER an packagist which is compatible with EXT:form in backend as part of the element wizard, in frontend while form rendering and in validation.

https://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/recaptcha
https://packagist.org/packages/evoweb/recaptcha

Answer (score 1):

You can use different extensions for this. Just try https://typo3.org/extensions/repository/?q=captcha.

Comment: Thanks für ur answer. The only problem is, the most of These extensions dont work under Typo3 V8.7 and them who do aren't documentated...

Comment: Would be nice to know which form you are using? powermail? core form? other one?

Comment: The core form :)

Comment: But now, i found out, that there is a Standard honeypot against spam :)

Comment: Cool. I just looked in the official documentation of the core form and some best practises for spam shields and captcha is missing. I'll tell the extension owner to add it.

Answer (score 1):

I think [sr_freecap](https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/sr_freecap/) is best solution for Captcha form in TYPO3. You can use this extension for both piBase and Extbase extension. It works for TYPO3 8 and TYPO3 9.

For Extbase extension settings [Extbase](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/sr_freecap/UsersManual/InsertingTheCaptchaInAnExtbaseFluidPlugin/Index.html)

For piBase extension settings [piBase](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/sr_freecap/UsersManual/InsertingTheCaptchaInAPiBasePlugin/Index.html)

Comment: Although this is an oldschool approach, it's a valuable answer. The big advantage here is in regard to privacy regulations. With freeCap, you don't need to use any external scripts.